# How to solve the Josephus puzzle in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to represent the [Josephus problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) in Python. Briefly, given a list `items`, every `k`th element is visited/marked until there are no items "untouched". How do I loop through the list in that manner and see what the last untouched element is?

My code is:

```
def josephus(items,k):
    while len(items)>1:
        del items[k]
    return items
```

But, when I am trying to

```
print(josephus([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],2))
```

It returns:

```
  line 3, in josephus
    del items[k]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Could you help me. Whats wrong with that code?

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do? What's the point of k? Because the way this code works, the length of your list will never be 0 except if k is 0 so the while loop will continue until you hit that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to delete the item at index `2`, but you deleted that item already.

Python indexes start at *0*, not at 1, so `2` is the **third** item. In other words, the list `[1, 2]` has a length longer than 1 (there are 2 items), but only the index `0` and `1` exist in that list.

You could add printing to your loop to see what is happening:

```
def josephus(items, k):
    while len(items) > 1:
        print(items)
        del items[k]
    return items
```

and call the function with a slightly shorter list to keep the output manageable:

```
>>> josephus([1,2,3,4], 2)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in josephus
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

This shows you are deleting the 3rd item each time, and the error is thrown when there are only 2 items left.

Instead of hardcoding the length, you could test for a length greater than `k`:

```
def josephus(items, k):
    while len(items) > k:
        del items[k]
    return items
```

Now the loop condition guarantees there is an element at index `k` to delete:

```
>>> def josephus(items, k):
...     while len(items) > k:
...         del items[k]
...     return items
... 
>>> josephus([1,2,3,4], 2)
[1, 2]
```

This is a lot of work to delete everything from a given index onwards however. Just use a *slice*:

```
def josephus(items, k):
     del items[k:]
     return items
```

The `[k:]` notation tells Python to address all items starting at index `k` until the end of the list (there is no value after the `:`).

However, if you are supposed to delete every `k`th element (so every 2nd or 3rd, etc.) then you are going about it the wrong way. Use slice notation again:

```
del items[::k]
```

I filled in the *3rd* slot of a slice, the *stride*. This will delete element `0 + 0 * k`, and `0 + 1 * k`, and `0 + 2 * k`, etc:

```
>>> items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> items[::2]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> del items[::2]
>>> items
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

If you are trying to implement the [Josephus problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) you cannot use this to delete items as the deletion has to be *circular*, at least not without calculating a new starting point for the next 'round' of eliminations. Use the `%` modulus operator to go around the circle, adjusting for the changing length:

```
def josephus(items, k):
    skip = k - 1  # deletion removes the item, so skip k - 1
    index = skip % len(items)
    while len(items) > 1:
        del items[index]
        index = (index + skip) % len(items) 
    return items[0]
```

Note that I now return the *one surviving item*, not the list.

The code keeps track of the *next* item to delete in `index`. We start at `k - 1` to adjust for 0-based indexing; the second item is at `1`. We then go around the 'circle' by incrementing by `k - 1` steps as we just removed the `k`th item and everything after will have moved up a step around the circle, and by using `%` to wrap back to the start of the list.

Comment: let me try:
skip = k - 1  # we get the index which we need to delete
index = skip % len(items) # we get modulo. for exapmle if len(items)=10 and k=4, then skip=3 and index=3%10 which is 10. is it wright so far?

Comment: @ArazHajiyev: no, `3 % 10` is still 3; only if the first operand is *greater* than `10` would you get a different number. The modulus operator gives us the *remainder* of a division. `12 % 10` gives us `2` because `12` divided by `10` would give us `1` plus a remainder of `2`.

Comment: @ArazHajiyev: you delete `2`, then your length is `9`. You then delete `4` and your length is `8`. Then delete `6` and now you have length `7`. You cannot delete `10` because there are not that many items so you wrap around to the start; `9 % 7` is `2`, so you delete `2`.

Comment: oh sorry, yes, 3%10 is 3. now my length is 9. and 3%9 is still 3.

Comment: But i got question:
why do we need to % ? skip=3 and  skip%10=3, It is same. then why do we need to get % ?

Comment: @ArazHajiyev: because `index` is incremented each time. What will happen when you go beyond the length of the list? How would you go *in a circle* at that point?

Comment: hmmm... this is hard to understand

Comment: @ArazHajiyev: see [Modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). Play with it in a Python prompt. Also see the [`divmod()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) which combines division and modulus operations into one.

Answer (score 0):

You need > k:

```
 while len(items) > k:
```

The last value items before the error is `[1, 2]` so `items[2]-> IndexError` as you are trying to index the third element of a two element list.

```
def josephus(items, k):
    while len(items) > k:
        del items[k]
    return items
```

Output:

```
In [27]: josephus([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],2)
Out[27]: [1, 2]
```

If you wanted to 2 to mean the second index you would need to -1 from k:

```
def josephus(items, k):
    while len(items) >= k:
        del items[k-1]
    return items
```

Now you would get a single element:

```
In [29]: josephus([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],2)
Out[29]: [1]
```

To just delete the `k'th` element:

```
def josephus(items, k):
    if 0 <= k < len(items):
        del items[k]
    return items
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, i understand it. But how can delete every k element in list?

Comment: simple `del items[k]` forget the loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete every `k` value in your original list starting at index `i`, just do

```py
del items[i::k]
```

In your specific case, it looks like you want to delete item `k` first, so do:

```py
del items[k-1::k]
```

This is so simple that you wouldn't wrap it in a function but if you want to:

To wrap it in a function:

```py
def josephus(items,k):
    del items[k-1::k]
    return items
```